Why the request is blocked when I sent data contained html tag and \n
I am using the Spring MVC and my task is to work with the backend and frontend only.
The system deployment and other distribution are handled by the other teams.
The problem I am facing is the Error 400 - Bad Request when the data that is sent contained <p></p> or other tags and \n. The request is successfully sent when I removed the <p></p> and \n from the data.
I can't really find the reason why the server keep blocking my request and I want to know the detail about how it works.
P.S: I used both form and json request at respective page.

No one here is going to be able to tell you an answer. Somewhere in the backend code, something is coded or configured to prohibit HTML input, presumably to avoid Little Bobby Tables. You will have to find it, or find someone who knows where it is. It is not an inherent characteristic of Spring MVC.
